# How to insert a row if the difference between 2 numbers is > than 0 in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, insert, rows

I have a simple excel table and I would like to insert `n` number of rows after a particular row

for example:

I would like to insert `n` number of rows if the difference of the `B` and `C` column is greater than 0.

And the number of columns to be inserted is the difference between those 2 cells.

But (if its possible ) would like to increase the number in the `D` column by the number of inserted cells but I don;t know what formula to use.

I have done a little macro in VBA but I dont have any experience with VBA and I can only do the first row and I can't copy the row down just insert the necessary number of rows!

My code:

```
Sub insertCells()

    Dim x As Long
    c = Range("C1").Value

    Dim id As Long
    id = Range("A1").Value + 1

    Dim y As Long
    b = Range("B1").Value

    Dim i As Long
    i = c - b

    Do Until i = 0
        Rows(id).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        i = i - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The first picture is what the cells looks like before the macro

[image]

The second is what the cells would look like if the macro was executed

[image]

Comment: I understand that the difference between "B and C"  say first row would be `10 - 13` which is `-3` which in turn means it's actually **lower** than `0`? Something is very unclear here...

Comment: C is always going to be higher than B, I'm sure.  When reading a spread, it's customarily read left-to-right.  What I'm unlear about is; shouldn't there be 5 records with a value of 2 in A?  One that already exists, plus 15 - 11 = 4 additional records.

Comment: On the code i tried (the one i made my self ) the formula was C-B , and if the number `n` is greater than 0 insert `n` rows. The idea behind this excel is that you start from the D1 cell and keep adding 1 every row you insert .The A column for every rows inserted its the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' finding last row used

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1 ' iterating from last row to 1st
        difference = Range("B" & i) - Range("C" & i) ' calculating the difference
        If difference < 0 Then ' if difference meets your criteria
            For j = difference To -1 ' how many rows to insert
                Rows(i).Copy ' copy the origin
                Range("A" & i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown ' insert the copied row
                Range("D" & i + 1) = Range("D" & i + 1) + Abs(j) ' increment column D
            Next
        End If
    Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

before

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my late reply !Yes that's it ! I will acept this answer as the correct one , but can you please explain it to me ? Like i said im not a good excel programmer and my as my real project its bigger and i wanted just to know the logic behind this code .Thank you :)

Comment: Yes i will accept it , but can you explain it to me in pour words how the code works?So i can implement it on my project ? That was my real goal for this bounty , to try to learn something new and use it on my project , If it's not too much bother  :)